# AVAudioSession record while playing weird issue

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

For part of an app that I'm making I need to record audio from the user. I have chosen to use `AVAudioRecorder` to do this.

The problem is that when I start to record audio, all audio playing on the device is paused. I then looked in the Apple docs for `AVAudioSession` and set the recording options to be: `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`.

The problem is that whenever I start recording, any audio playing on the device switches from the main external speaker to the small phone (call) speaker.

My goal is to record audio while still allowing all other audio from the device to be outputted through the main speaker.

How can I achieve this?

Here's my code currently:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if(recorder != nil){
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }//end if
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try using `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker`. According to the [AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories) reference:

> When using this option and no other audio route (such as a headset) is available, session audio will play through the device’s built-in speaker. When not using this option, and no other audio output is available or selected, audio will play through the receiver (a speaker intended to be held to the ear).